# How to test with jquery if an attribute equals ""

Tags: jquery, arrays, attributes, selector

I have looked high and low for a solution and I have found many that come close to an answer but cannot find something that solves my exact problem.

I have jquery removing `display: none;` style attribute.

This sets the style attribute equal `to style=""` as there are no other styles set inside the style attribute.

How do i test and build an array of all the elements that have the style attribute set to `style=""`

NOTE the elements in question are part of a table with the id of `#returnedTable`

and the td elements look like `<td style="" rel="22">`

I am trying to return an array of the data contained in the rel attribute for each td element that has a style attribute set to `style=""`.  Note it will be mixed in with td elements that look like

```
<td style="display: none;" rel="24839">
```

Comment: a more appropriate way would be to add a class & then select by using the classes rather than the way you are trying to do.

Comment: This sounds like an unwise way to find the elements you want.  The style attribute can be empty for lots of other reasons.  If you're removing display: none with JS, you should just mark these objects with a class name or a custom attribute and make it a lot more foolproof to find them again with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rels = [];

$("#returnedTable td[style='']").each(function () {
  rels.push( $(this).attr("rel") );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all elements with style set to "" like this:

```
var eles = $("*[style='']");
```

If you just want the rel attribute values, you can do:

```
var arr = $("*[style='']").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("rel");
}).get();
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/P2cZ9/2/)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response.  Which solution is better?  This one or the third one?  Question is in regards of how much of the dom is selected and how it is searched.  I do not fully understand all selectors and they work. (post is question is by Tomalak)

Comment: +1, then - what's the difference between `get()` and `toArray()`?

Comment: @Wes - it would be a good idea to narrow the search down to a particular container. In my example I assume you want to search the entire DOM for matching attributes. Tomalak's solution assumes you are looking for table cells within a table with the id of 'returnedTable'.

Comment: @Tomalak - it is *exactly* the same thing. I'm not having a good day. I think I woke up dumb.

Comment: @karim The question was genuine - I've never used `get()` without a parameter. :)

Comment: @Karim79 You seem to be searching the entire dom for `"*[style='']"` and then using map (which I am about to go read about) and he is using `"#returnedTable td[style='']"` which seems to be more specific as it is possible that other elements in the document could possibly have the style attribute set to "".  Additionally he is using the each function to iterate the returned dom elements.  I guess the question is in two parts.  Is it better to map or iterate then add to the array?  Is it better to use your selector or his?

Comment: @Wes: That's a matter of preference. Use what you like better. Performance-wise they won't be any different from each other.

Comment: @Karim79 && Tomalak, You have both introduced jquery functions that I have never used which I must go study now... thanks lol.. no really thank you both.  I guess since both solutions are correct, what in your opinion is the fastest and easiest on resources.  This will help me mark the correct answer for other readers.

Comment: Lets say for argument sake that both selectors were the same `"#returnedTable td[style='']"`  Which solution would be the fastest?

Comment: @Wes: Stop worring about performance so much. Both selectors are valid, and both will be lightning fast.

Answer (score 1):

Why not give those elements a particular class with jquery? You could easily build an array of their `rel` values then.

```
var rels = [];
$('#returnedTable tr td.myClass').each(function(){
   rels.push($(this).attr("rel"));
});
```

Comment: from what I am understanding, you are saying as i remove the display: none style attribute to add a custom class that is common among each that has the display: none removed?

Comment: yes that's right. you could then target those tds with $('td.myClass').attr('rel');

Comment: This is a better approach to the issue as the issue i have is because of a design flaw that your solution will fix.  I have +1 you for this, please leave this answer up for others to read.

Answer (score 0):

What about an [attribute CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)?

```
[style=""]
```

Happy coding